# Limit Ransack drop down options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I am using Ransack and it is working really well on our Data model. Now the issue is, in the dropdown, it shows us all the 15 option like id, name, age, gender, type, location, SSN, company, status etc.

I only want 3 options to be shown in the drop down say name, gender and location (all being text fields). How can I do it ?

data_controller.rb

```
@search = Data.search(params[:q].try(:merge, m: 'or'))
@datum = @search.result(:distinct=>true).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
```

data.html.erb

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <div class="form_search">
                <%= search_form_for @search, url: search_data_index_path, html: { method: :get, class: "data_search" } do |f| %>
                <%= f.condition_fields do |c| %>
                <%= render "condition_fields", f: c %>
                <% end %>
                <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Add Conditions", f, :condition %></p>
                <br>
                <div class="actions">
                    <%= f.submit "Search", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
                </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
 if auth_object == 'admin'
  super
 else
  #mention all the attributes u wish to search
  super & ['assigned_to'] 
 end
end
```

By default, all the attributes of a model are considered ransackable attributes. To override it add the above method in the model